# Add phone numbers to ABPerson

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, abperson

I try to put in a string for each of the values and I get errors, can someone demonstrate how to add numbers to an `ABPerson` here is my attempt:

```
if (_cellNumber) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(_lastName), NULL);
}

if (_workNumber) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABWorkLabel, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(_lastName), NULL);
}

if (_defaultNumber) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(_lastName), NULL);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add phone number to existing contact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834379/add-phone-number-to-existing-contact)

Answer (score 2):

To set the record's phone numbers, you need to use the following code:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)phoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(pet, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);
```

To read more about this, check out [my tutorial.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63885/address-book-tutorial-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

The numbers in ABRecord are a multi-value property that you can not set like that.

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316825/how-to-edit-a-contact-from-address-book-in-iphone)